# Multiplication isn't commutative?

Tags: javascript, commutativity

The ECMAScript language specification [specifies](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5.1) that the multiplication operator is commutative (A*B==B*A). However this doesn't hold if A or B includes an assignment operator. For example if I type the following into a browser's console:

```
 var x = 1;
 (x + 2) * ((x = 4) + 1);
```

gives 15, however:

```
 var x = 1;
 ((x = 4) + 1) * (x + 2)
```

gives 30.

Or does commutative mean it is commutative once all the variables have been resolved to their values? However the spec talks about the "* operator", not the mathematical multiplication operation.

Comment: Interesting portion is `(x = 4)` in expression `((x = 4) + 1)` first will be `3 * 5` second `5 * 6`

Comment: "Commutative" pretty obviously refers to the values of the evaluated expressions. You cannot define the `*` operator to be concerned about the order of evaluation of its operands, since those could go very deep (e.g. `foo() * bar()`).

Comment: Why do you care? Yes, multiplication is commmutative. But in this case you are using different values in the two cases, due to the effect of the assignments. So it's like saying that `(1 + 2) * (4 + 1)` not being equal to `(4 + 1) * (4 + 2)` is somehow evidence of non-commutativity. In any case, probably doing these assignments in the middle of a computation is not the best idea. I am not sure what the spec says, but it is quite possible that a particular engine might choose to evaluate the two sides in reverse order, or even in parallel.

Comment: Yes so that's what I'm asking when the spec says it is commutative is that talking about the math operation or the * operator. The reason I care is because for a module in uni we have to write a spec for a simple language that we write a compiler for so I've been looking at specs for other languages.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is x+2 in the second example is 6 instead of 3, becase You already asigned x=4;

meaning after:

```
((x = 4) + 1)
```

what happens is

```
(x + 2) == (4 + 2) == 6
```

and

```
(4+1) * 6 = 30
```

this is normal behavior

Comment: I realise this is normal behaviour and why it happens, just not the certain on the definition of the spec.

Comment: The definition of how `*` acts becomes relevant only when you're down to the `5 * 6` situation. Before then, `*` isn't involved at all. It's commutative when called, not from some sort of AST point of view, that wouldn't make much sense -- then no function or operator is commutative.